# Identify words with ascending characters from text file

Tags: java, loops

I am having a fair amount of trouble trying to write a program that counts the amount of ascending words. I have tried a few different methods to solve this but cannot seem to get it working.

If anyone could help me revise the code to work properly it would be appreciated.

Comment: add words to Array and Sort it..

Comment: you are not resetting i after each word is read.

Comment: the logic you used seems wired to me.

Comment: Do not remove question contents or mark titles with "solved" tags.

Comment: Don't delete your question on the pretext that it has been resolved. It might be of interest to others. Just flag the accepted answer. That's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use hasNext() and next() for the input, because if you use nextLine() then it'll take the whole line in the file (or until it finds a newline).

Try this:

```
i=0; //i should start from 0
while(inputFile.hasNext()){
    theWord = inputFile.next();
    ascending = true; //remember to reset ascending to be true as default
    i = 0; //reset i to 0 again
    if(theWord.length() >= 2){
        while(i < theWord.length() - 1){
            if(theWord.charAt(i) > theWord.charAt(i + 1)){
                 ascending = false;
                 break; //since we know that its not ascending, just move on to the next word
            }
            i++;
        }
        //if after the check ascending still true that means the word is ascending
        if(ascending==true){
            System.out.println("+ " + theWord);
            totalNum = totalNum + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with the help of [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) for reading the file:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class AscendingWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> strings = FileUtils.readLines(new File("file.txt"));
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (ascending(string)) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean ascending(String string) {
        if (string.length() <= 1) return true;
        else return string.charAt(0) < string.charAt(1) 
            && ascending(string.substring(1));
    }
}
```